# Setting JoinColumn parameters insertable and updatable to null

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have seen a couple of examples on the Internet about using JoinColumn like the way in the example below.

Actually, there are two questions I want to ask you about this partcular example. Can't we just get rid of the "optional" parameter by adding a "nullable=false" parameter to the JoinColumn. Are there any differences between optional and nullable entity relationship-wise?. What are the advantages of setting insertable and updatable to false in the joincolumn? Is this done to ensure that Employee entity cannot update the Department entity?

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  // ...

  @ManyToOne(optional=false)
  @JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Department department;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`optional = false` on the ManyToOne is a runtime instruction for the persistence framework to interpret when building java objects.  `nullable = true` on the JoinColumn is for setting up the database schema and may or may not be interpreted at runtime depending on your persistence provider.

Normally that JoinColumn mapping is done that way to indicate that the relationship is managed from the other side, by the Department.

You would likely have:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID")
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

Over on your department, and you'd create new employee-department relationships by adding them to the collection there, rather than setting a Department on the Employee.  That's why you mark the Employee's department as non-updatable, because the Department "owns" the ability to modify the relationship.

Comment: Actually, there's no need for a JoinColumn on Set<Employee> employees in the Department entity, since the foreign key is already on the Employee already. And Since the employee has a ManytoOne relationship with department and since it contains the foreing key, does that not make it the owner of the relationship? Also, in this situation, Deparment would have OneToMany(mappedyBy=department) as this is a bidirectional relationship.

Comment: That would be a bidirectional relationship owned by the ManyToOne side, yes.  I illustrated an alternative, a relationship owned by the OneToMany side, where JoinColumn is used on the OneToMany instead of mappedBy.  It is true, it is not necessary.  It's an alternative that offers slightly different behavior.  And it is mapping that normally uses updatable=false and insertable=false on the ManyToOne side, as you inquired about.

Comment: I think at the end of the day setting updatable and insertable to false in JoinColumn essentially works the same as setting updatable and insertable to false in Column (non-relationship fields). You simply cannot modify the (foreign key) field. Well, this approach is better suited for legacy databases.